# More efficient way to append a list item after some text in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So at the moment, I have some code that allows me to insert a [ListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item) after a paragraph in Google Docs. The only issue that I have with it is that it seems overly complicated for what I'm trying to accomplish. Here is my code...

```
  var search = "This is a test"
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
  var regExp = new RegExp("("+search+")", "g");
  var text;
  for (var i = body.getNumChildren() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    text = body.getChild(i).asText().getText()
    if (regExp.test(text)) {
      body.insertListItem(i + 1, "This is a test bullet.").setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setBold(false)
    }
  }
```

> Line 1: This is where you put the text into where you want to append the ListItems under
>
> Line 2: This just grabs everything in the body of the document
>
> Line 3: Creates a regular expression with the text that was inputted in line 1
>
> Line 4: Just sets the "text" variable
>
> Line 5: Loops through all the child elements of the body element
>
> Line 6: Gets the text of each of the child elements
>
> Line 7: Test to see if the text in the "search" variable is equal to some text in the body of the document somewhere and grabs that child
>
> Line 8: Inserts a bullet one child beneath the child that is found in line 7

**This code below is what I thought would do that for me, append a ListItem below some text**

```
var search = "This is a test"
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
body.findText(search).getElement().asText().appendListItem("Test bullet")
```

I wanted it to look something like this:

This is a test

- Test bullet

But instead with the code directly above I just got this error **`TypeError: Cannot find function appendListItem in object Text. (line 116, file "Code")`**

The thing that I am just very confused about is when I run some code that looks like this it works without any error but obviously it appends it to the very top of the document. So then why doesn't my code directly above work and how can I make it work?:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
body.appendListItem("Test bullet")
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Text objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) represent text, the lowest level of document structure. One can't have other elements, such as a list item, inside of Text. This is why Text objects don't have `appendListItem` method; they have `appendText` method.

Actually, the only parts of a document that can contain ListItem are Body and header/footer/footnote elements: see the [document structure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document). So it is necessary to add ListItem to Body, and this needs to be done with `body.insertListItem(index, text)` method to have it correctly positioned.

If you only want to add one list item after the first search result, the following will do the job:

```
var search = "This is a test";
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var found = body.findText(search); 
if (found) {
  var elem = found.getElement().getParent();
  var index = body.getChildIndex(elem);
  body.insertListItem(index+1, "Test bullet");
}
```

Note that the element you get with `found.getElement()` is Text, which is not a child of Body: it is going to be inside of something else, likely a Paragraph. Hence the call to `getParent` to get something that is probably* a child of Body.

If the insertion was meant to be global, run a while loop with `findText`:

```
var search = "This is a test";
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var found = body.findText(search); 
while (found) {
  var elem = found.getElement().getParent();
  var index = body.getChildIndex(elem);
  body.insertListItem(index+1, "Test bullet");
  found = body.findText(search, found);
}
```

*Important: this won't work if the search term is buried deeper, say in a Paragraph in a Table or in Equation. Then one needs to call getParent more than once until getting to Body. I didn't try to implement this additional loop, because

- it's not clear that you'd want list items in random places like Equations;
- it would be more complex than the loop-over-children-of-Body approach that you already have.

Comment: Is "If the insertion was meant to be global, run a while loop with findText:" does that mean that it finds all of the instances of "This is a test" and inserts "Test bullet" underneath each of them?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. By passing the previous search result to `findText` as the second parameter, one gets another search result (or `null`  if there aren't any more).