# Insert list item into a specific Table of google doc

Tags: list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

This is the point.
I've followed the suggest linked here [More efficient way to append a list item after some text in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868193/more-efficient-way-to-append-a-list-item-after-some-text-in-google-docs) ,whose very helpfull tom me. But i have the problem mentioned at the bottom.
My placeholder is inside a known table within a google doc.
I've tried several ways to figure it out, but i didn't achieve.
Here below there is the portion of code of interest.
Note:

- "CarattCentralGas1" is an array of values;
- "DescrizioneCentralGas" is another array of values;

My intent is to insert a list, created if the if condition is true, at the placeholder place and than remove it.
Any ideas would be great!`

```
for (var i=0; i < CarattCentraleGas1.length; ++i) 
       { var ValueToTest = CarattCentraleGas1[i][0];
       Logger.log(ValueToTest)
       if (ValueToTest ==='Presente') 
       { var valueToextract = DescrizioniCentraleGas[i][0];
       var search = '%Placeholder%';
       var Table1 = body.getTables()[0];
       var found = Table1.findText(search); 
       while (found) {
       var elem = found.getElement().getParent().getParent();
       var index = Table1.getChildIndex(elem);
       Table1.insertListItem(index+1, valueToextract+';');
       found = Table1.findText(search, found);}
      Logger.log(valueToextract)}
              }
    var Table1Text = Table1.editAsText().replaceText('%CarattCentrale1%',"");
`
```

this is the template document I want to edit with the script.
[image]

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes, I get this errore: "Exception: the element does not contain the specified child". The reference error line is the one of the code below

var index = Table1.getChildIndex(elem);
Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I see. Is the `for` necessary at all? Inserting the entire array directly would insert the list in the table. Do you have an example of how would the final result look like?